# PHP GuzzleHttp GET CookieJar value

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, guzzle, cookiejar

To begin with, sorry for my bad English. When I try to do:

```
$cookieJar = $this->client->getConfig('cookies');
$cookieJar->toArray();

return var_dump($cookieJar);
```

I've got an `object(GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar)#176 (2) {...`

But why when I try `$cookieJar->getCookieByName('sessionid');` And then var_dump. I've got same object, not only mine cookie. What's wrong? How can I got cookie's `sessionid` value? Thanks in advance. I'm new with CookieJar and GuzzleHttp.

Comment: Do you have an answer? If so, could you post it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$sessionid = $cookieJar->getCookieByName('sessionid')->getValue();
```